# Silverlight Scrollviewer not displaying with bound treeview

Tags: binding, silverlight-4.0, treeview

I have a 4 row, 1 column Grid wrapped in a ScrollViewer.
The rows are Treeviews that are bound to hierarchy (nested Lists) of objects.
I'm using a HierarchicalDataTemplate to lay out the TreeViewItem nodes and their children / ItemTemplates.

My problems is that whenever I expand the TreeViewItems, the vertical scrollbar is **not** showing up.
Oddly enough, the horizontal scrollbar *will* show up when I expand out an AccordionItem that is part of the child nodes.

I have tried creating an event handler that calls UpdateLayout() whenever a TreeViewItem is expanded, but that's not causing the scrollbar to appear.  I have tried calling UpdateLayout() against the TreeView, the Grid, and the ScrollViewer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this became painfully obvious after some experimentation.

Specifying the **Height** property for the ScrollViewer was the missing piece that made everything work as it would be expected.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              Height="350">  <!-- THIS was the missing piece!! -->
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Controls:TreeView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOne}" 
       ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListOneTemplate}" >
    </Controls:TreeView>

    <Controls:TreeView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ListTwo}" 
       ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListTwoTemplate}" >
    </Controls:TreeView>

  </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

FWIW, I tried a number of other solutions including setting heights and maxheights for the Grid, GridRows, and TreeView.  I also tried creating an event to set the height of the scrollviewer whenever the grid height changed, and an event that fired off cascading UpdateLayouts() whenever a tree view item changed.

Setting the height on the ScrollViewer was the only approach I found that made everything work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can set the row definition:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/> // tree view position
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

The treeview will take the free space of the screen, showing scrollbars if necessary.